# Finding $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+\frac{x}{n})^nx^{\frac{1}{n}}}\, d\lambda$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, measure-theory

**The question**

Compute the limit:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{\displaystyle\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^nx^{\frac{1}{n}}}\ \mathrm{d}\lambda$$

**My attempt**

It is clear to see that point-wise the integrand has limit $e^{-x}$ however I am struggling to call upon the proper limit theorem. Since the integrand is decreasing. Also I cannot seem to bound it by an integrable function as neither $\frac{1}{x+x^2}, \frac{1}{x}$ or $\frac{1}{x^2}$ are integrable.

**Going forward**

I think this must use the dominated convergence theorem but I cannot seem to find a suitable function. I was considering $f_2(x)$ and then using a substitution $u = x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ but this becomes awfully complicated. Any help would be great.

Comment: @Sumanta thank you for your edit my latex isnt great! :)

Comment: This might be one of the cases where it's best to break it into two integrals: $0$ to some constant $M$ (usually $1$), then $M$ to $\infty$.

Comment: actually, $f_2(x)$ is a good choice, since you can prove it is integrable

Comment: what is $\lambda$ in this case?

Comment: The integral would just be (the integrand times x)+constant of integration because  λ  is a constant in terms of x unless it is a function of x. Not too rigorously, but the integrand coverges to y=1 [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/f3wwtpjxoe). This means the limit is λ from 0 to infinity which diverges to infinity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of trying to find an upper bound given by a formula, think about the problem points. Here your integral has issues at $0$ and at infinity. Also, you don't have to bound for all $n$, just *eventually*.

At zero the integrand is basically $x^{-1/n}$, which is integrable for $n\geq2$. So, say on $[0,1]$ we can take $1_{[0,1]}\,x^{-1/2}$.

At infinity you can use that, for $x\geq1$,
$$
\Big(1+\frac xn\Big)^{-n}\,x^{-1/n}\leq \Big(1+\frac x2\Big)^{-2}.
$$
In all, the function
$$
g(x)=1_{[0,1]}\,x^{-1/2}+1_{[1,\infty)}\,\Big(1+\frac x2\Big)^{-2}
$$
is an upper bound for all $n\geq2$, and integrable. So Dominated Convergence applies.